# Ethernet Device Name in OpenSolaris

Tags: ethernet, opensolaris

In Linux, I usually refer Ethernet devices as `ethN`.

What is OpenSolaris standard naming for Ethernet devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use scanpci which is the equivalent of lspci in linux to display the list of PCI devices in your system.

Once you identify the type of NIC you have in your system refer to http://opensolaris.org/os/community/device_drivers/projects/longriver/nic_driver_list/ to locate the exact driver for the card. The interface will be based on the driver. i.e., If you have only one Broadcom Gigabit ethernet card then 'bge' will be the driver to use and 'bge0' will be the name of the interface.

Answer (score 6):

The only time you should need to use something like scanpci is if there is no driver available for your NIC and you are trying to figure out what 3rd party driver to add.

NIC naming on OpenSolaris is device specific by default, so it might be e1000g0 on one machine (using a common Intel chip) or bge0 (using a common Broadcomm chip). While **ifconfig -a** will certainly show all configured interfaces, you will get a lot more out of **dladm**, which can tell you about all configured and unconfigured interfaces.

The dladm command is what you can use to interrogate your NIC cards and modify network properties.  This allows "one-stop shopping" for link aggregation, device property setting, virtual NIC creation, rate limiting, renaming, etc. You can use:

root@opensolaris: **dladm show-phys**

LINK         MEDIA                STATE      SPEED  DUPLEX    DEVICE

e1000g0      Ethernet             up         100    full      e1000g0

e1000g1      Ethernet             unknown    0      half      e1000g1

e1000g2      Ethernet             unknown    0      half      e1000g2

e1000g3      Ethernet             unknown    0      half      e1000g3

to list all your interfaces.  You can also rename the the link name using:

dladm rename-link $oldname $newname

like

root@opensolaris: **dladm rename-link e1000g1 dmz**

root@opensolaris: **dladm show-phys**

LINK         MEDIA                STATE      SPEED  DUPLEX    DEVICE

e1000g0      Ethernet             up         100    full      e1000g0

dmz          Ethernet             unknown    0      half      e1000g1

e1000g2      Ethernet             unknown    0      half      e1000g2

e1000g3      Ethernet             unknown    0      half      e1000g3

There is also much more you can do, check out Ben Rockwood's [blog post on the topic](http://www.cuddletech.com/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=999).

Answer (score 1):

In linux, you are lucky. Solaris names ethernet devices after manufacturer (I assume driver).
If you have an Intel e1000 nic you'll probably have a device named "e1000g1".

Anders

Answer (score 0):

If OpenSolaris has correctly identified your NIC, you can get a list of all current network interfaces (including virtual interfaces, loopbacks and ipv6) by running:

ifconfig -a